# ¿Por qué nunca sale del bucle?

Tags: c++, búsquedas

Estoy tratando de resolver un problema, para hacer una pirámide ascendente de un bloque en 2 arrays usando la cantidad mínima de movimientos (remover/agregar).

Para ello estoy usando una "búsqueda" y una simulación para ir probando como quedaría acomodada, pero no llego a entender porque no sale del while después de encontrar el numero de movimientos mínimo en ambos(3)...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

#ifndef MAXN
#define MAXN 300001
#endif

using namespace std;

int a[MAXN],b[MAXN];
int n;
// Simulacion
int f(int x){
    int m=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        m+=abs(a[i]-x);
        m+=abs(b[i]-x); 
    }
    return m;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    cin>>n;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)cin>>a[i];
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)cin>>b[i];
int l=1,ma=0,mi;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    ma=max(ma,max(a[i],b[i]));
int in=0,x=0,x2=0,aux=0,aux2=0;
mi=ma;
while(l<ma){
    l=(mi+in)/2;

    x=f(l);x2=f(l+1);
    //if(x<f(aux2))id(break;//if(aux<=x2)break;
    if(min(x,x2)==aux){
        if(x==aux)aux2=l;
        else aux2=l+1;
        break;
    }

    if(x<x2){
        aux=x;
        aux2=l;
        mi=l-1;
        //l--;
    }else{
        aux=x2;
        aux2=l+1;
        in=l+1;
        //l++;
    }
}
cout<<f(aux2);
return 0;
}
```

El lado de la izquierda muestra la entrada, y la derecha , como debería quedar la pirámide de cubos

[image]

```
 -------------



 Entrada | Salida
=============
3  |      3

1 2 3 
3 2 2
-------------
```

Comment: Lo siento pero no termino de entender el problema... No veo relación entre los datos de entrada que usas y las imágenes que presentas. Por otro lado, no veo eso que comentas de que el programa ya ha hayado el mínimo número de movimientos... si se queda atascado en el `while` no va a imprimir nunca nada, ya que el `cout` está fuera del bucle.

Comment: creo que tu problema esta en el if, porque `f(l) <f(l+1)` va ser siempre `true` es decir que siempre le sacas 1 a l `mi = l-1` y teniendo el como condicion del while `l<ma`, llego a la conclucion que `l = (mi+in)/2` va a ser siempre mas chico que `ma`

Comment: @Federico en el if varia , no siempre es **true**

Comment: @eferion Aquí esta el planteamiento del problema https://github.com/COCANATION1/PracticasCbtis/blob/master/4Fant%C3%A1sticos/problem_3/problem_3.md